# VBA: Using & inside of an equation

Tags: excel

I want to make a formula with a & inside it but VBA thinks its a concatenate symbol

""&"" does not work, are there any other tricks?

My formula:

```
Sheets("Elasticity").Cells(iRow, 38).Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & "All_Models!$W$2:$W$" & nrow & ",All_Models!$G$2:$G$" _ & nrow & ",Elasticity!L" & iRow & ",All_Models!$AL$2:$AL$" & nrow & ",Elasticity!AK" & iRow & _ ",All_Models!$B$2:$B$" & nrow & "," & "" <= "" & "&" & "ElasticityA" & iRow & ")"
```

I want to transform:

```
"" <= "" & "&" & "Elasticity!A" & iRow & ")"
```

into:

```
"<="&Elasticity!A2)
```

Comment: Can you please post the formula you're trying to create in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

How about just this:

```
dim s as string
s = "my_complicated_formula" & "&" & "and_another_formula"
```

Comment: My formula is complicated

Sheets("Elasticity").Cells(iRow, 38).Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & "All_Models!$W$2:$W$" & nrow & ",All_Models!$G$2:$G$" _
                & nrow & ",Elasticity!L" & iRow & ",All_Models!$AL$2:$AL$" & nrow & ",Elasticity!AK" & iRow & _
                ",All_Models!$B$2:$B$" & nrow & "," & "" <= "" & "&" & "Elasticity!A" & iRow & ")" 

Your method does not work, I get a FALSE instead of a number

Comment: I want to transform

 "" <= "" & "&" & "Elasticity!A" & iRow & ")"

into

"<="&Elasticity!A2)

Comment: Does this work?
 Sheets("Elasticity").Cells(iRow, 38).Formula = _
    "=SUMIFS(All_Models!$W$2:$W$" & nrow & ",All_Models!$G$2:$G$" & _
    nrow & ",Elasticity!L" & iRow & ",All_Models!$AL$2:$AL$" & nrow & ",Elasticity!AK" & iRow & _
    ",All_Models!$B$2:$B$" & nrow & ",<=Elasticity!A" & iRow & ")"

Answer (score 0):

```
s="foo" & Chr(38) & "bar"
```

Where chr(38) = &

Answer (score 0):

```
...All_Models!$B$2:$B$" & nrow & ",""<=""&" & "Elasticity!A" & iRow & ")"
```